# Is there a list of which UK E-Numbers aren't vegetarian or vegan?

Tags: health, is-it-vegan, labeling, resources, food-additives

I often see lots of E-Numbers in ingredient lists and I know some probably aren't vegetarian, and some definitely aren't vegan.. Especially as all ofthem seem to be made out of crushed up bugs! They apparently aren't that good for you either...

Is there a definitive list or an Android app which lets you to look up these numbers to see what they're made of and if they are vegetarian/vegan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [E stands for Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_number) so this advice is valid for all the EU.

[Here](https://www.vegsoc.org/Enumbers) or [here](http://elated.co.za/which-e-numbers-are-vegan/) you can find a list of those E numbers that are not vegetarian/vegan and [here](http://www.eatplantsnotanimals.com/about/vegan-friendly-e-numbers/) you can find another which also specifies the different functions of the veg-friendly ones.

Comment: The list of the ones that are definitely of animal origin is not that big, it would be better if it could be included in the answer